# Cmd script for cycle

Tags: windows, cmd

My job is to write a small script in cmd which compares two variables(number) a and b.

If a is smaller than b then it counts from a to b with 1 steps
if a is bigger than b then it counts from a to b backwards.
Here is the code:

```
if a LSS b (for /L %%g in (a, 1, b) do echo %%g) else (for /L %%g in (a, -1, b) do echo %%g)
```

if i set a to 1 and b to 10 it only writes out 2 zeros.

```
set /a a=1
set /a b=10
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables need to be wrapped in `%` marks to access them

```
set a=1
set b=10

if %a% LSS %b% (
    for /L %%g in (%a%, 1, %b%) do echo %%g
) else (
    for /L %%g in (%a%, -1, %b%) do echo %%g
)
```